# Routhian mechanics on a symplectic manifold

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism

We can define the Lagrangian on the tangent bundle of the configuration space, and the equations of motion can be written as extremizing $\mathcal S[\gamma] = \int L(\gamma,\dot\gamma)\,\mathrm dt$. Alternatively, we can formulate Hamilton equation as specifying the extremal path of the functional $$\mathcal S[\gamma] = \int_{\gamma} \vec p\cdot\mathrm d\vec q + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}H(\gamma) \,\mathrm dt,$$ where the path $\gamma$ is on the phase space, which I restrict to the cotangent bundle and not an arbitrary symplectic manifold.

It is worth noting that the Lagrangian is usually convex in $\dot q$. But in the Hamiltonian version, the path is in a space with twice the dimension, and doesn't depend on first derivatives at all. Is it possible to formulate Routhian mechanics along the same line? Perhaps it would involve specifying a partially-tangent, partially-cotangent bundle. And more generally, can this construction be taken to arbitrary symplectic manifolds?